# How to convert insert sql statement to delete sql statement using JSQLParser

Tags: java, sql, sql-insert, sql-delete, jsqlparser

I want to convert insert sql statement to delete sql statement using [JSQLParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser), How this can be achieved ?
for example here is sample insert sql

```
INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename, job, sal, comm, deptno, joinedon) VALUES (4160, 'STURDEVIN', 'SECURITY GUARD', 2045, NULL, 30, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-02 06:14:00.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));
```

post conversion to delete sql will be following

```
DELETE FROM emp WHERE empno=4160 AND ename='STURDEVIN' AND job='SECURITY GUARD' AND sal=2045 AND comm=NULL AND deptno=30 AND joinedon=TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-02 06:14:00.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF');
```

Here is code thus far

```
import net.sf.jsqlparser.JSQLParserException;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.expression.operators.relational.ItemsList;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.schema.Column;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.Statement;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.delete.Delete;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.insert.Insert;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename, job, sal, comm, deptno, joinedon) VALUES (4160, 'STURDEVIN', 'SECURITY GUARD', 2045, NULL, 30, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-02 06:14:00.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));";
        final Statement statement;
        try {
            statement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(insertSQL);
            if (statement instanceof Insert) {
                final Insert insertStatement = (Insert) statement;
                System.out.println("insertStatement: " + insertStatement);
                List<Column> columns = insertStatement.getColumns();
                for (final Column column : columns) {
                    System.out.println("column: " + column);
                }
                ItemsList itemsList = insertStatement.getItemsList();
                System.out.println("itemsList: " + itemsList);
                final Delete deleteStatement = new Delete();
                deleteStatement.setTable(insertStatement.getTable());
                System.out.println("deleteStatement: " + deleteStatement);
            }
        } catch (JSQLParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am building this project using maven here is pom dependency.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>oracle.insert.delete.jsqlparser</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle_from_insert_to_delete_using_JSqlParser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsqlparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Part of legacy code, These insert statement are written for setting up test data, I want to clean up test data automatically once test is complete. And not depend on poorly written delete statement in teardown.

Comment: If your table has a `primary key`, then it's enough to only include that value in the `DELETE`; the rest of the column list is redundant. Otherwise, it's a bit unclear what your code should be doing because all of the data is hard-coded in the `INSERT`.

Comment: Interesting question. Can you elaborate a bit on *why* you want to do this? How's the INSERT statement generated and why do you need a matching DELETE statement for it? Also, if you have control over the part of your code which generates the INSERT, it'll almost certainly be much easier to generate both the INSERT and DELETE statements at the same time instead of generating only the INSERT and then parsing it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a way to do it (the added code starts from "`// get the list of values`"):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename, job, sal, comm, deptno, joinedon) VALUES (4160, 'STURDEVIN', 'SECURITY GUARD', 2045, NULL, 30, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-02 06:14:00.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));";
        final Statement statement;
        try {
            statement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(insertSQL);
            if (statement instanceof Insert) {
                final Insert insertStatement = (Insert) statement;
                System.out.println("insertStatement: " + insertStatement);
                List<Column> columns = insertStatement.getColumns();
                for (final Column column : columns) {
                    System.out.println("column: " + column);
                }
                ItemsList itemsList = insertStatement.getItemsList();
                System.out.println("itemsList: " + itemsList);
                final Delete deleteStatement = new Delete();
                deleteStatement.setTable(insertStatement.getTable());

                // get the list of values
                ExpressionList expressionList = (ExpressionList) itemsList;
                List<Expression> values = expressionList.getExpressions();

                // create the "column = value" expressions list
                List<Expression> expressions = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
                    // create the "column = value" expression
                    EqualsTo equalsTo = new EqualsTo();
                    equalsTo.setLeftExpression(columns.get(i));
                    equalsTo.setRightExpression(values.get(i));

                    // add it to the list
                    expressions.add(equalsTo);
                }

                // glue together the expressions with "ANDs"
                // it is now our where expression
                MultiAndExpression whereExpression = new MultiAndExpression(expressions);

                deleteStatement.setWhere(whereExpression);

                System.out.println("deleteStatement: " + deleteStatement);
            }
        } catch (JSQLParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It generates this delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM emp WHERE (empno = 4160 AND ename = 'STURDEVIN' AND job = 'SECURITY GUARD' AND sal = 2045 AND comm = NULL AND deptno = 30 AND joinedon = TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-02 06:14:00.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'))
```